# How to safely remove resolve-url?

Tags: npm, package, resolveurl

I have an npm package [resolve-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url) in my React Native project. The package is deprecated, and I'm not using it, so I want to remove it. However, after I run `npm uninstall resolve-url` to [uninstall per npm's documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall), my project no longer runs with `npm start`!

**How do I safely remove resolve-url?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **How do I safely remove resolve-url?**

It turns out that my project depended on resolve-url through another package, source-map-resolve.

Solution:

1. `npm uninstall source-map-resolve`
2. `npm uninstall resolve-url`
3. I deleted the newly created `package-lock.json` because my project used `yarn.lock`.
4. I cleaned up remaining references to source-map-resolve and resolve-url in my `yarn.lock`.

[More info](https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url)